# What's the difference between "Zombie, Run! Zombie Finder" and "Zombies, Run!"?

Tags: fitness

There are two different augmented-reality zombie games which work on Android devices:

1. ["Zombie, Run! Zombie Finder"](http://spelochappar.store.aptoide.com/app/market/net.peterd.zombierun/16/35579/Zombie%2C+Run!)
2. ["Zombies, Run!"](https://zombiesrungame.com/)

It's confusing that they have such similar names.  Please tell me about the difference between them.

Comment: I'm not so sure that the question is Android-independent. "Zombie, Run! Zombie Finder" only works on Android, and not on any other OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## "Zombie, Run! Zombie Finder"

The first of the two games is called the "Zombie, Run! Zombie Finder".  It is free and open-source software.  The project founder is Peter Dolan.

According to an old [comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/hzvas/any_good_exergaming_apps/) by Reddit user ["participating"](https://www.reddit.com/user/participating), it is:

> [A] fun way to get some running/jogging/terrifying brisk walks done ... It also has a multiplayer mode, which I have yet to try out.

<sup><sub>[Several people](https://code.google.com/p/zombie-run/people/list) have had commit rights over the years, including Peter Dolan (project founder), Gabriel Francis (Spanish co-translator), as well as "empeamtk" and "agent.craig".</sub></sup>

<sup><sub>Development started [in April '09](https://code.google.com/p/zombie-run/source/list?num=25&start=25).  Version 1.3 was released to the Google Play store [in April '13](https://web.archive.org/web/https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.peterd.zombierun&hl=en).  At [last count](https://web.archive.org/web/https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.peterd.zombierun&hl=en), the game had been downloaded more than one million times.  If you look at the [most recent code commits](https://code.google.com/p/zombie-run/source/list), you'll see that [revision r207](https://code.google.com/p/zombie-run/source/diff?spec=svn207&r=207&format=side&path=/trunk/ZombieRun/AndroidManifest.xml) mentions a "Version 1.3.1".  But I'm not sure whether or not such a version was ever released.  The game is currently unmaintained.  But, because the game is open-source software, a new maintainer could step up at anytime.</sub></sup>

<sup><sub>Mr. Dolan has [moved onto other things](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/zombie-run-users/MTHfqVXyqW4/9XuUOPxOkjoJ).  The game is [gone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.peterd.zombierun&hl=en) from the Google Play store now.  I have no idea why; if you do know, please enlighten me.</sub></sup>

You can [download the game from Aptoide](http://spelochappar.store.aptoide.com/app/market/net.peterd.zombierun/16/35579/Zombie%2C+Run!).  You can find basic usage instructions [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20111026103745/http://www.zrli.org/zombierun/about.html).

---

## "Zombies, Run!"

"Zombies, Run!" is the second of the two games.  It is completely separate from the first game, and comes from a different development team.  It's a closed-source "freemium" game.  It's maintained by Six to Start Ltd., a British game-development company.

It seems to me that this game was [conceived independently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombies,_Run!#Development), though I am surprised that the development team didn't choose a different name.  It was released [in Feb. '12](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombies,_Run!), and is available for iOS, Android, and Windows Phone.

The Google Play store [app description](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sixtostart.zombiesrunclient&hl=en) writes:

> *Zombies, Run!* is a ... running game and audio adventure ... .  Every run becomes a mission ... with our ... audio drama putting you at the centre of your very own zombie adventure story.  While you run to [a] mix of ... audio drama and ... songs from your own playlist, you’ll collect supplies to grow your base back home.  ...  *Zombies, Run!* works anywhere and at any speed. You can jog in a park, run along a beach, or walk along a trail.  It even works on treadmills.

You can download the free version of the game [here](https://zombiesrungame.com/).

If you post questions about this second game over on our sister site Arqade, please use the tag [ [`zombies-run`](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zombies-run) ].

---

Dear readers:  This post is marked as "community wiki".  Please [edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/120955/edit) and improve it.